# AFNetworking issue with UStream API request for channel's video list

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, afhttprequestoperation, nsurlerrordomain

This is probably something simple that I am just overlooking.  I am trying to make an AFHTTPRequest from uStream's API using AFNetworking.  I should be getting a JSON payload response back that lists all the videos on a uStream Channel. Here is my code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.ustream.tv/channels/12321320/videos.json"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success");

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"failed");
}];

[operation start];
```

Everything works fine when testing in a browser but when trying to use AFNetworking I get a NSURLErrorDomain failure. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and it worked fine with me.

Comment: What response are you getting back?

Comment: I get the same json response.

Comment: I was using the simulator.  For some reason it doesn't work with the simulator. Stupid mistake.  Thanks. I was using Charlie for some HTTP Proxy with the simulator not too long ago.  It must have done something with my security certificates on the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was fine but there was an issue with my iphone simulator. Reset Content and Settings did the trick. Thanks to k6sandeep for the help.